# pthread array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

I have a struck with an array of pthread pointers. Each thread is meant to read a different data stream

```
typedef struct {
  // ...other stuff
  pthread_t *threads[MAX_STREAM_COUNT];
} stream_manager;
```

And when I want to start reading:

```
void start_reading(stream_manager *sm, int i) {
   // do some pre processing stuff
   pthread_create( (pthread*) &sm->threads[i], 
                              NULL, 
                              read_stream_cb, 
                      (void*) sm->streams[i]       );
}
```

When I want to stop reading:

```
void stop_reading(stream_manager *sm, int i) {
   iret = pthread_join(*sm->threads[i], NULL);
   if(iret != 0) {
     perror("pthread_join returned with error:: ");
     printf( "pthread_join returned with error:: %s\n", strerror(iret) )
   }
}
```

For now, my read_stream_cb function simply prints the name of the stream its reading from.

```
void* read_stream_cb(stream *strm) {
   stream *s = (stream*) strm;
   prinf("%s\n", s->name);
}
```

In the main program, I initialize 2 streams with different names. I call run start_reading(), sleep(3) and stop_reading()). The program prints the stream names fine for 3 seconds, but the pthread_join does not return successfully. It returns `3` and prints out

```
pthread join error: Operation timed out
pthread_join returned with errer:: No such process
```

I think this may be a pointer issue? I may just be confused with order of operations with these pointers in the join `pthread_join(*sm->streams[i], NULL);` . I'll look into that more.

Comment: Is it `sm->streams` or `sm->threads` ?

Comment: you put `(void*) sm->streams[i]` into `pthread_join()` ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) takes a `pthread_t*` as its argument, this is passing a `pthread_t**`:

```
pthread_create( (pthread*) &sm->threads[i],
```

as `sm->threads` is an array of `pthread_t*`. Change `stream_manager` to:

```
typedef struct {
  // ...other stuff
  pthread_t threads[MAX_STREAM_COUNT]; /* No longer array of pointers. */
} stream_manager;
```

and remove the unnecessary cast from the call to `pthread_create()`.

[`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) takes a `pthread_t`:

```
pthread_join(sm->threads[i]); /* Not sm->streams[i]. */
```